# Javascript - see if object contains function, if so, return it

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function which takes in a String. The function checks if the object in the list has this function(functionName). If it contains that function, how can I return it? Obviously, `return list[i].message would work`, but thats not what im after. I want do use the parameter functionName in this case.

```
function message(){
    return "hello";
}

function test(functionName);
    listLength = list.length;
    for(i = 0; i < listLength; i++){
        if(list[i].hasOwnProperty(functionName}{

            return (?)
    }
}
var x = test("message");
alert(x);
```

Grateful for response

Comment: `return list[i][functionName]`

Comment: you would also want to add to the `if` condition `&& typeof list[i][functionName] == "function"`

Answer (score 0):

the comment from [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) is right, but you have to consider that having a function detached by its owner will screw the scope, so you will no longer have access to the *right* `this` object

```
var test = {
    number: 0,
    testFunction: function() {
        return this.number;
    }
}

console.log(test.testFunction());  // output: 0

var x = test.testFunction; 
console.log(x());                  // output: undefined
```

maybe you should use

```
var y = test.testFunction.bind(test); 
console.log(y());                  // output: 0
```